# How to extract path from object?

Tags: inkscape

Take a look at the following example picture

[image]

The letter A is a set of paths (after converting to paths from object). It's two paths really, the outline of the A and then the interior triangle is another path. But when you select it, they act like one combined path, even though they are not connected to eachother.

How would I extract the path from the triangle by itself as it's own independent path that I can fill and stroke?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `Path > Break Apart` to split that letter **A** into two unique objects.

[image: before] [image: after] [image: color]

Comment: Ah I was messing with that but didn't know I needed to select ALL the points of the object. Thanks!

Comment: Ha. No problem! :)